# Second jQuery button click isn't firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do something ostensibly simple in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edwinkohlbrenner/0yodg7gb/) and it is not working. Essentially I have an h1 html tag with class "me" and a button with class "poo". The first click works and my css color changes, however the second click does not work?

```
$(".poo").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $(".me").css("color","green");
   var haha = $("<button>Click Me!!!</button>");
   $(this).after(haha);
   $(haha).addClass("changer");
   $(this).hide();

});
$(".changer").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   $(".me").css("color","black");
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: the new button I am creating. http://jsfiddle.net/edwinkohlbrenner/0yodg7gb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the second click to the parent element:

```
$(document).on('click', '.changer', function() {
//function here
});
```

Comment: I just have a h1 and button in my html what would the parent be?

Comment: that worked by why? what does it mean when a click handler is already bound?

Comment: Your second button didn't exist at `document.ready` - it was added dynamically, so you need to find an element that already exists and which can delegate to the new element when it is created. See @Cuong Le's explanation, below.

Answer (score 2):

The `changer` click handler is bound before the element exists. Try using the `$.on` method instead.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('body').on('click', '.changer', function() {...})
```

This works because the event handler is bound to the document `body`, which already exists on the page. When there is a click anywhere in the body, jQuery will check if the clicked element matches the selector `.changer` and execute the callback if so.

Alternatively, you could just bind the `$('.changer').click` event within the first callback.

Comment: like this? $(".changer").on("click",function(e){blah...});

Comment: I don't have a body tag

Comment: I tried putting $('.changer').click inside the first click callback after $(this).hide(); and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0yodg7gb/7/

```
  $(".poo").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); 
       $(".me").css("color","green");
        var haha = $("<button>Click Me!!!</button>").addClass('changer');
        $(this).after(haha);
        $(haha).addClass("changer");
        $(this).hide();
        bindClick();
     });

function bindClick(){
$(".changer").bind('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       $(".me").css("color","black");
       $(this).hide();
});
}
```

Comment: this is very cool. So your unbinding the click event and "re-establishing" it? Next level stuff

Comment: remove unbind. in certain cases you need it. but not in your case.

Comment: were bind and unbind deprecated?